# Data structure suited to store number of integers in sorted order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a question related to data structures.

Your system measures temperature every second. The input data is an integer. At any point in time i should be able to retrieve the highest 5 temperature records. What is the best data structure to store this data.

Answer (score 2):

A heap, or equivalently, a sorted array would work.

Checking if your new time needs to be inserted at all is `O(1)`. Checking the location is `O(log n)` (where `n` is 5). Depending on the optimization, with five elements, the move and insert could be `O(n)` or `O(1)`.